# Bulk insert using dotConnectForPostgreSQL

Tags: devart, dotconnect

Do we have any bulk copy or bulk insert mechanism into PostgreSQl by using dotConnectForPostgreSQL provider from C#?

I am trying to insert the data(multiple sheets with lakhs of records) from xlsx to PostgreSQl by using c#.
But didn't find any suitable method in devart. Bulk insert is available in NpgSQL but i don't want to use Npgsql to avoid driver related issues(specifying kind for date time fields etc..)

Regards,
Someshwar

Comment: Please try to avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood

Comment: I am trying to insert the data(multiple sheets with 100 thousands of records) from xlsx to PostgreSQl by using c#. But didn't find any suitable method in devart. Bulk insert is available in NpgSQL but i don't want to use Npgsql to avoid driver related issues(specifying kind for date time fields etc..)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PgSqlLoader class that is available in dotConnect for PostgreSQL Professional Edition: [https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/?Devart.Data.PostgreSql~Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlLoader.html](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/?Devart.Data.PostgreSql%7EDevart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlLoader.html).